# I want to define a class for receiving some information from the user and then printing them in the C++ console

Tags: c++, string, class

I am going to define a class with the following features. However, when I run the compiler, I encounter with some errors relating to string variables. I do not know how to solve the problem for this code.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Name
{

   public:

        int age;
        int id;
        std::string name ;
        std::string family ;
        std::string fathername ;


        Name()
        {
           name = "l";
           family = "p";
           fathername = "mh";
           age = 26;    
           id = 80;
        }




        friend void setinformation()
        {
               std::string n;
               std::string f;
               std::string fn;
               cout << "Please Enter Your Name" << " ";
               cin >> n ;
               name = n;
               cout << "Please Enter Your Family" << " ";
               cin >> f ;
               family = f;
               cout << "Please Enter Your Father Name" << " ";
               cin >> fn ;
               fathername = fn;
               cout << "Please Enter Your age" << " ";
               cin >> A ;
               age = A;
               cout << "Please Enter Your id" << " ";
               cin >> i ;
               id = i;  

        }
};



main()
{
    Name a;
    a.setinformation();

    cout << a.age << endl << a.name;

    getch();
}
```

Here are the errors I have received:

```
General: TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64-bit Release
Executing g++.exe...
g++.exe "D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp" -o "D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.exe" -g3 -I"D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include" -I"D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++" -L"D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" -L"D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -static-libgcc -g3
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp: In constructor 'Name::Name()':
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:26:15: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
            id = 80;
               ^

D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp: In function 'void setinformation()':
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:15:21: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Name::name'
         std::string name ;
                     ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:39:13: error: from this location
             name = n;
             ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:16:21: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Name::family'
         std::string family ;
                     ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:42:13: error: from this location
             family = f;
             ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:17:21: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Name::fathername'
         std::string fathername ;
                     ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:45:13: error: from this location
             fathername = fn;
             ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:47:20: error: 'A' was not declared in this scope
             cin >> A ;
                    ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:13:13: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Name::age'
         int age;
             ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:48:13: error: from this location
             age = A;
             ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:50:20: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
             cin >> i ;
                    ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:14:7: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Name::id'
   int id;
       ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:51:7: error: from this location
       id = i; 
       ^
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp: In function 'int main()':
D:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\Class Name.cpp:64:7: error: 'class Name' has no member named 'setinformation'
     a.setinformation();
       ^

Compilation failed after 0.24 seconds with errors
```

Comment: Why a class for this? Why not just a simple free function?

Comment: As I am going to add another class to this and use inheritance concept.

Comment: Well read your errors that would show you what's wrong. But for starters  you dont declare variable a and I in your set information function. You also dont need std::string If you have included <string>. I'm not sure what the point of your constructor is

Comment: I forgot to declare A and i. But even after declaring them, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `main` needs a return type
- There are unused includes
- Use the constructor initializer list and not the constructor body
- Make `setinformation` a member function and not a friend function
- Don't use `using namespace std;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Name
{
   public:
        int age;
        int id;
        std::string name;
        std::string family;
        std::string fathername;

        Name() : age(26), id(80), name("l"), family("p"), fathername("mh")
        {}

        void setinformation()
        {
               std::cout << "Please Enter Your Name" << " ";
               std::cin >> name;
               std::cout << "Please Enter Your Family" << " ";
               std::cin >> family;
               std::cout << "Please Enter Your Father Name" << " ";
               std::cin >> fathername;
               std::cout << "Please Enter Your age" << " ";
               std::cin >> age;
               std::cout << "Please Enter Your id" << " ";
               std::cin >> id;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Name a;
    a.setinformation();

    std::cout << a.age << '\n' << a.name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your through comments Thomas.